# Parse query string in Express/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

I have an app set up using ExpressJS and EJS templates. Let's say I have an index of users (/users) with links in my template for sorting results:

```
<a href="/users?sortOrder=oldest">
<a href="/users?sortOrder=mostActive">
```

However, when I add pagination to the page, the links should be updated as such:

```
<a href="/users?page=2&sortOrder=oldest">
<a href="/users?page=2&sortOrder=mostActive">
```

In general, what are the strategies for updating such links? Should these links be created server-side and inserted into the template? If so, are there any modules for URL parsing/updating? Or should this be handled dynamically (such as via JQuery)?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, variable amount of parameters is really bad for you because sometimes you need extra validation.

Im not friend of storing on the session but thats valid too.

And do all this kind of things serverside always.